# Access node server state from ruby

Tags: ruby, node.js

If I have a node program that creates a server running on my local machine that keeps a state variable, is there any way to retrieve this state using ruby?  Specifically:

```
var http = require('http')
var state=6;
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(state);
}).listen(8080);
```

How could I find out the value of state using ruby?

Comment: Your Node code doesn't look like it's actually serving your state variable. You have to fix that first.

Comment: Yes, you could make an HTTP request from Ruby to your Node.js server at http://localhost:8080 to get the value. But as Linuxios mentioned you need to make sure you return the value in Node.js rather than an empty string.